# How can i improve my count(distinct id) query in mysql laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql

I am using three join and fetching more than 4 million records for now it is 1.5 million.

Below is my query, can you please take a look?

```
SELECT count(distinct enrollments.userid) AS aggregate 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN enrollments ON users.userid = enrollments.userid 
INNER JOIN classes ON enrollments.classid = classes.classid 
INNER JOIN assigned_courses ON assigned_courses.courseid = classes.courseid 
WHERE assigned_courses.`oneroster_permission_id` = 147
```

Here is the explanation of my current query.

[image: explanation of my current query]

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) to get the execution plan, then add it to your question together with relevant `show create table <tablename>;`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have added explain screenshot here

https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Explain_count.PNG

Comment: It asks me to log in. Can you make it public? And then just [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/123705/edit) your question and add the link in there. It would be even better to give it as text if possible, but thats more important for the "create" statements.

Comment: I have added the link of explanation result in my question , can you please help me ?

Comment: If you can add the tables structure too.. Do you really need to count all rows/combinations? No usable conditions for WHERE?

Comment: The WHERE you edited in there totally changes any advices we might give you.. and it invalidates the EXPLAIN too, so think about what do you really want to optimize and then give proper details so we can help you.

Comment: Yes , i have edited the where condition as per your remind
I am attaching updated explain count link along with tables involve into it(every table have primary index)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmjj1hpu7c0r7qo/Explain_count.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe7744l6c73rkmw/assing_courses.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/37wqg6lwlqwgeaw/enrollments.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9aj17n81j943iy/users.png?dl=0

Comment: Really, please use `show create table <tablename>`, not screenshots of some GUI, those are not very readable and are missing important info (for example details about existing indexes). It is easiest to just use commandline mysql client and copy/paste the outputs, they are quite well formatted.

Comment: @jkavalik Please take a look
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyqfsx5jzrwqg5c/show_tables.png?dl=0)

(https://www.dropbox.com/s/me4t7w2wfth1dt5/show_table_restpart.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Can you join me on the chat session created by me :

(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97944/room-for-anand-mishra-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this gives you the right answer:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS aggregate
    FROM  enrollments AS e
    WHERE  EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  classes AS c
            JOIN  assigned_courses AS ac ON ac.courseid = c.courseid
            WHERE  ac.oneroster_permission_id = 147
              AND  c.classid = e.classid 
      ) AS x
```

Note:  I tried to avoid the `DISTINCT` by avoiding any `JOINs`.  `JOINs` tend to explode the number of rows, only to force you to use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` to get back to what you wanted.  But, I guess there could be multiple occurences of a `userid` in `enrollments`.

No matter how it is written, I think the performance will be poor.  Notice how the query needs to come at it from two sides, one to filter on 147, the other to connect to enrollments.classid.